# How to use parameter in SQL statement in Excel?

Tags: sql, excel, parameters

Experts,

I have a Excel file which use pure SQL statement to query a remote SQL server database. I wanted to add a parameter to the SQL statement defined inside the Excel. How to do that?

Please see the screen shot.

Thanks!

[image: SQL in Excel]

Answer (score 0):

There's this Manage Parameters option in the ribbon. You can try from here [in the image you posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD3xr.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. How to reference the parameter name inside the SQL. I tried &someParameter&, it didn't work.